# Find the optimum graph for the max flow problem using network's edge capacity matrix

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization

I want to calculate the maximum flow of the network and am attempting to do that with `FindMaximumFlow[edge capacity matrix, s, t, "OptimumFlowData"]`, which in my case is

```
F = FindMaximumFlow[({
{0, 2, 2, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 6},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
}), 1, 10, "OptimumFlowData" ].
```

While I do get a result with this, I want to be able to use the command `F["FlowGraph"]` to get a network showing the optimal solution.

[Here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximumFlow.html) you can see that by this command the optimal graph is returned when the first parameter is the graph itself instead of the edge capacity matrix.

How can I get the optimal graph from using `FindMaximumFlow` with the capacity matrix or get the graph from the edge capacity matrix so I can use the graph similarly to how it's used in the example in documentation? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build a graph using edge capacity matrix:

```
g = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[{{0, 2, 2, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 6}, {0, 0, 0, 
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}} /. {0 -> Infinity}];

data = FindMaximumFlow[g, 1, 10, "OptimumFlowData", 
   EdgeCapacity -> EdgeWeight];

data["FlowGraph"]
```

[image]

Comment: Why does `data["FlowTable"]` not work?

Comment: Oh that's great, thank you!